# Do I need a transit visa for a trip with connections in both London and Dublin?

Tags: uk, canada, transit-visas, lhr, ireland

I'm travelling from Delhi, India to Toronto, Canada via LHR and DUB. It's a 3 legged journey with stops at London Heathrow and Dublin. I have valid visitor visa for Canada. I understand that I'll need to go through border control at LHR since I'll be taking a LHR-DUB flight, which is a domestic flight. Will I need a UK visa? Which one? Will the border agent let me pass through without one since I have a Canada visa and an onward journey ticket?

Answer (score 2):

> Will I need a UK visa?

You will need an **Irish** visa, assuming you are an Indian National, gov.uk states :

> > Transiting without a visa
>
> > You may be eligible to transit without a visa if:
>
> - you arrive and depart by air
> - have a confirmed onward flight that leaves on the day you arrive or before midnight on the day after you arrive
> - have the right documents for your destination (for example, a visa for that country)
>
> You must also have an Irish biometric visa (marked ‘BC’ or ‘BC BIVS’
> in the ‘Remarks’ section) and an onward flight ticket to the Republic
> of Ireland.
>
> E-visas or e-residence permits are not acceptable for transiting
> through immigration control without a visa.
>
> All visas and residence permits must be valid.
>
> You will not be able to transit without a visa if a Border Force
> officer decides you do not qualify under the immigration rules.

You won't need a UK visa though, provided you apply in India as an Indian national and your visa in endorsed `BC` or `BC BIVS` (through the [British-Irish Visa Scheme](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/british-irish-visa-scheme/british-irish-visa-scheme))